# unexpected end of file even with the <?php tag

Tags: php, html

So im using AJAX to load my table data ... here is my ajax :

```
function loadSupplies(){
 $.ajax({
  url : '../controller.php',
  data : {loadTable : 1},
  success : function(data){
   $('#tbodySupplies').html(data);
  }
 });
}
```

so inside my controller is this:

```
if(isset($_POST['loadTable'])){
  $sql = $init->query("SELECT * FROM supplies");
  foreach($sql as $supplies) : ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?= $supplies->stock_no; ?></td>
    <td><?= $supplies->supplies_name; ?></td>
    <td><?= ($supplies->quantity <= 5) ? "<span class='text-danger'>" . $supplies->quantity . " in Critical Level</span>" : $supplies->quantity; ?></td>
    <td><?= $supplies->unit_of_measure; ?></td>
    <td><?= $supplies->type; ?></td>
    <td width="10">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="manage(<?= $supplies->id; ?>)">Manage</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
}
```

I don't seem to find an error but why is it giving me 'unexpected end of file' even though i already put the complete php tag. Please help.

Comment: Is that the entire file?

Comment: Could this be the problem? `$supplies->quantity; ?></td>`

Comment: probably not the error but you're missing a closing `</tr>`

Comment: no, sir. Its just part where i get the error, shall i include the query ?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to copy the <tr> but its complete

Comment: the supplies quantity, i had it with the shorthand if else, sir. And it works pretty well just when i want to use ajax, it gave me an error

Comment: The error applies to the whole file, not just one part of it

Comment: thank you, i already terminated the statement however the error still is the same :(

Comment: It is in another part of the file. This whole bit is syntactically correct. I also wouldn't use a shorthand echo with the ternary but that's just personal preference.

Comment: okay okay, ill try and look at it

Comment: just an additional info sir, when i end my php file with '?>' the error goes to that line. I dont really understand tho

Comment: @Fear you have unclosed `if`/`foreach` statement (or anything similar). Provide all file here so we can help.

Comment: okay okay sir, wait

Comment: The error line reported with this type of error will never be correct. You missed a closing brace somewhere so the script is skipping everything else looking for it. It gets the the end of the file still missing and just reports the error at that line. It doesn't think about you intentions, it just wants the block to close.

Comment: so it could be that my error is not where i think it is, it could be at the beginning sir ? I started this part with if(foo = bar) so maybe before i even started this thing, it already threw an error ?

Comment: I FOUND IT!!! i just removed the closing tag of php sirs :D thank you very much for thy help ^_^ more beautiful projects to come :D